# Define a new variable by concatenation of two other variable names in VBS

Tags: variables, vbscript, concatenation

I am writing a long script for two weeks ago and now due to the way whose it's written, I need to define a variable name by concatenation of two existing variable names. I don't want to concatenate their values but the variables themselves in order to make a new variable.
That may sound ridicule, but given the situation, I have no other choice.

```
Is it possible?
```

Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support introspection, so you can't dynamically resolve variable names from within the script. However, there might be a possible way to go about. If instead of variables `a` and `b` you use a dictionary with keys `"a"` and `"b"` you could concatenate those key names to produce a new key `"ab"`:

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d.Add "a", 23
d.Add "b", 42

newkey = ""
For Each key In d.Keys
  newkey = newkey & key
Next

d.Add newkey, 2342
```

However, you might be able to get a better answer if you described the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.String together multiple variables (a and b) into one variable called `strFullName`.

```
a.strFirstName = “Test”
b.strLastName = “Automation”
```

Use concatenation, so that the variable `strFullName` is equal to “Automation,Test” using variables from a and b listed above.