# Call a generated variable name in vbScript

Tags: variables, vbscript, ibm-midrange

I am creating a macro for use within Personal Communications 5.8 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/readme/readV58.html

The macro will run on various 'regions', which have a 4 character text identifier on screen. e.g. TRND or TRNI. I have seven of these regions.

Throughout my macro, some steps will use slightly different values depending on that region. So my arrays may look something like this;

```
screenTRND = Array ("One", "Two", "Three")
screenTRNI = Array ("Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges")
```

Rather than build in seven different 'If' statements throughout this macro, does anyone know of a way of calling a single 'If' statement, that will adapt depending on the region identified?

For example, have a single 'If' statement with something like;

```
If screen & region (0) = "One" Then MsgBox "Success"
```

So that if the region is TRND, all is good. But if the region is TRNI, the test gives a false result.

Of course, in the above, the array value is only looking at 'TRND' for an array value and not looking at 'screenTRND' (as well as other problems with that statement, but those don't add to or remove from my query).

I found the following question, which I felt takes me the right direction, but I've not been able to get it working.

[Define a new variable by concatenation of two other variable names in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650321/define-a-new-variable-by-concatenation-of-two-other-variable-names-in-vbs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DO NOT** construct variable names on the fly. VBScript can't really handle this, and even if it could it would still be bad practice anyway.

Use proper data structures for handling your data, in this case a dictionary:

```
Set screen = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
screen.Add "TRND", Array("One", "Two", "Three")
screen.Add "TRNI", Array("Apples", "Bananas", "Oranges")
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
If screen(region)(0) = "One" Then MsgBox "Success"
```

Or you could check if the region is actually defined in the first place:

```
If screen.Exist(region) Then
    WScript.Echo "Region " & region & " exists."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Region " & region & " does not exist."
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. I've taken your first couple of lines (Set and the two screen.Add lines), then followed those with "MsgBox screen(region)(0)", thinking I'd see the text "one". Instead, I'm getting a mismatch [undefined] error. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @Russ The variable `region` is either empty or has a value that is not present in the dictionary. Check if the value of `region` is actually present in the dictionary first (see code sample at the bottom of my answer).

Comment: Bang on the money, I was testing your help at the start of my code and had not yet set the value for `region`. The number of entries for each `region` does differ, but Ubound has that covered. This will vastly shorten the code required... Thank you very much for your answer. Really well explained and solved my issue.